# Loading SQL Server driver via RJDBC on Ubuntu RStudio Server throws Error in .jfield("java/lang/Integer", "Ljava/lang/Class;", "TYPE")

Tags: r, sql-server, rjava, rstudio-server

`rJava` and `RJDBC` load without error on this Ubuntu (Azure Data Science image) installation of RStudio Server:

```
dyn.load('/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/server/libjvm.so')
library(rJava)
require(RJDBC)
Loading required package: RJDBC
Loading required package: DBI
```

However, when I go to load the MS SQL Server driver it throws this error:

```
drv  <- RJDBC::JDBC("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
Error in .jfield("java/lang/Integer", "Ljava/lang/Class;", "TYPE") : 
  cannot find class java/lang/Integer
```

Re-running it or trying to proceed to make a JDBC connection seems to result in RStudio Server throwing an "error in transmission" pop-up and restarting the R session.

When I search on the error message I find Java language threads pertaining to `Int` vs `Integer` though in this case I wonder if it's to do with the `rJava` installation, which was simple for the server's terminal installation of R but which took extra work to get `rJava` to load with RStudio Server (updating environment variables, the `$PATH` and using `dyn.load`)...

Comment: Welcome back to the R tag! This feels like an environment issue. The Azure Data Science image may have older [MSSQL JDBC driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/release-notes-for-the-jdbc-driver?view=sql-server-ver15#previous-releases) or R libraries (RJDBC, rJava, etc.) not compatible with each other. Try upgrading all versions if you can.

Comment: @Parfait Thank you kindly :)  I will try that and update the thread. The image actually didn't come with R so I will focus on the driver itself.

Comment: I have found a work-around by using `con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), .connection_string =...` though the underlying JDBC problem remains unsolved.

Comment: So workaround is to use an ODBC driver? Once again, I believe it is the components that come pre-installed in [Azure Data Science Image](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/virtual-machines/data-science-virtual-machines/) of which you may not have control. Reach out to Azure maintainers. I can assure you the latest SQL Server JDBC drivers and RJDBC does work in Ubuntu.

Comment: @Parfait I will, thanks. Correct, the workaround just bypasses the problem. Yes I also have RJDBC working in Ubuntu in general, I think that RStudio Server may be playing a role as well. I'll open some help tickets.